# Como guardar en valor de una variable cada hora?

Tags: typescript, variables, condiciones, variables-globales

Tengo la variable principal x que se va actualizando y quiero guardar su valor cada hora pero no logro conservar el datos.

Como puedo guardar el valor de x a una hora sin perderlo?

Lo que he intentado es esto, pero cuando deja de cumplirse la condición, mi variable pierde el valor leído

```
Time(x)
{
    let date = new Date();
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var y;
    if (minutes == 47) {
        y = x;
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes ser un poco más detallad con lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: la variable x se va actualizando constantemente y lo que quiero es guardar su valor cada hora, pero no logro mantener el dato, ya que  cuando deja de cumplirse la condicion se reinicia la variable, no se como leer lo que vale y guardar ese valor hasta que se vuelva a cumplir la condición

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con un `setTimeout`

```
const guardar = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Aqui pones tu logica
  }, 1000 * 60 * 60)
}

guardar()
```

Donde la función guardar se va a ejecutar cada 60 minutos